# How can i get a vSphere VM's workgroup and list of users?

Tags: powershell, vmware, vsphere, powercli

I am trying to do so both via the API ("VirtualMachine" class, in C#) and via power cli commands - without any luck.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: you should provide us with some code you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

The Vsphere apis don't provide that sort of info. Use vsphere apis (powercli etc) to get the vm's ip address and then talk to the VM's os directly from there, using PowerShell remoting or similar.